# Violating Content Security Policy directive in environment Ember Cli

Tags: security, ember.js, google-chrome-extension, ember-cli, content-security-policy

I have a built a Music Player Component with ember consuming the SoundCloud Api

Suddenly in Chrome i start getting this error notification in my console anytime i play a song in my application plus the songs does not play.

See the error

[image]

*Report Only] Refused to connect to 'https://ec-media.sndcdn.com/YEqcIen0Pkq6.128.mp3?f10880d39085a94a0418a7ef69…fe493d321fb2a6a96186dcb97beab08f3cea5ad8b42d543c3edc7371f0eb5b2b00ba96395e' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self' data: cf-media.sndcdn.com ws://localhost:35729 ws://0.0.0.0:35729 http://0.0.0.0:4200/csp-report".*

It is complaining about the "connect-src 'self' data: cf-media.sndcdn.com ws://localhost:35729 ws://0.0.0.0:35729 http://0.0.0.0:4200/csp-report".*"

This is because after bit of research i have modified in `environment.js` the content security policy like this

```
contentSecurityPolicy: {
  // 'connect-src': "'self' data: https://cf-media.sndcdn.com",
  'connect-src': "'self' data: cf-media.sndcdn.com",
},
```

Before my change the problem was the same and this was the console log error

[image]

So my question is, how can i give these permission in order to not violate the 
Content Security Policy directive for `'connect-src'`? What other action have i to take now?

Again the problem is only in Chrome

Comment: What does it have to do with [tag:google-chrome-extension]?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your property is not well-formed.  Try:

```
contentSecurityPolicy: {
    'connect-src': "'self' https://ec-media.sndcdn.com",
},
```

Comment: Plus i have noticed one song is connected to https://ec-media.sndcdn.com ... and the rest to https://cf-media.sndcdn.com ......

Comment: i have also tried'connect-src': "'self' 'localhost:4200'", and  'connect-src': "'self' *",

Answer (score 0):

To more clearly address the content security policy and avoid further conflicts with more subdomains, I suggest changing it to be:

```
contentSecurityPolicy: {
    'connect-src': "'self' https://*.sndcdn.com",
},
```