# Ember App not playing sound in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, audio, ember.js, ember-cli, soundcloud

I have built an ember music app consuming favorite songs by SoundCloud using the api of this [project](https://github.com/lrdiv/ember-soundcloud). You can see the demo [here](http://soundcloud.lrdiv.co/)

From a couple of days i have noticed that only in Chrome any song i play, the sound and and the stream do not work, in the other browsers ( Safari and Firefox) it works well as usual.

I thought at the beginning it was violating the content Security Policy directive in environment Ember Cli. See the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35684348/violating-content-security-policy-directive-in-environment-ember-cli) but although i have solved it, the problem is still there, plus there is not console log error

These are all the actions i have taken in Chrome to fix it, none of them was successful

- Removed any chrome extension
- Clear cache and deleted cookies
- Tried in incognito mode
- Reinstalled Chrome

My chrome is update , the version is 48.0.2564.116 (64-bit)

At the moment the sound and the stream do not work in my app and also in the demo http://soundcloud.lrdiv.co/ but in all the other browsers yes.

So question is, what other actions can i take? Should i maybe downgrade a Chrome Version as last try? Is it only a browser problem?

I have also followed these [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30648413/my-sounds-are-not-playing-in-chrome) with not solution

Comment: It looks like the player uses Flash (FF requires me to install it when I go to your demo). Have you looked into Flash as the source of the issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SoundCloud API v3 Stream not working in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34203097/1677912).

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution here: https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-javascript/issues/39

If you deactivate the flash here chrome://plugins/ it works out